# Parse JSON to TypeScript object

Tags: angular, typescript

Let say I have a Object:

```
class Person{
id: number;
name: string;
}
```

And Json from API:

```
{
"id": "10",
"name": "Person Name",
"email": "per@ho.com"
}
```

How to convert from JSON to Person object, excatly variables that is in Person class?

I tried this:

```
Object.assign(Person.prototype, this.jsonList))
```

but i'ts not working

Comment: Add a constructor, and call it: `new Person(json.id, json.name)`?

Comment: Method Object.assign  assigns all properties, but email doesnt exists in Person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about what properties are declared in a class is "metadata", and is not directly accessible. Hence, there is no straightforward way to copy only those properties present in a class from some input which might contain additional unwanted properties, other than explicitly enumerating them.

The feature of JavaScript/TypeScript which **does** have access to such metadata is **decorators**. Therefore, to solve your problem in a generalized way requires such a decorator. The decorator could generate a static method which copied just those properties which actually exist on the class. That would look like that:

```
@ConstructFromJsonWithExtraGarbage()
class Person {
}

const sally = Person.constructWithExtraGarbage(
  {id: 1, name: "Sally", email: "sally@mail.com"});
```

Actually writing this decorator is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: I don't need email. Object.assign method copies all properties

Comment: there can be a lot of unnecessary properties in Json. I need exactly which are described in Person. I need mapping approach.  But Object.assign extends Person with all properties

Comment: So replace Object.assign() by `this.id = person.id; this.name = person.name;`. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: This is the problem, I must write all properties by hand, I cant find auto mapper.

Comment: Can you write example how to use decorators?

Comment: What you want is a "class decorator". You can find more information at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html.

Comment: Thank you very much